# Включение mod_deflate на Apache 2.4.18

Tags: gzip, apache2.4

В самом `index.php` включаю сжатие через `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");`
На сервере хостера проверял все работает и данные жмутся. При запуске на локальном Apache, браузер выдает:

> "Страница, которую вы пытаетесь просмотреть, не может быть показана,
>   так как она использует неверную или неподдерживаемую форму
>   компрессии."

Все пакеты которые у меня относятся к Apache.

```
rpm -qa apache\*

apache-mod_actions-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_mime-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_authz_dbm-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_authn_anon-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_authn_file-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_authz_user-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_vhost_alias-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_alias-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_negotiation-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_dir-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_env-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_headers-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_rewrite-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_usertrack-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_authz_groupfile-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_unique_id-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_info-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_authz_owner-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_authz_core-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_autoindex-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_setenvif-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_authz_host-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_cgi-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_include-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_auth_basic-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_imagemap-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_expires-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_filter-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_version-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_mime_magic-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_substitute-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_status-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_unixd-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_log_config-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_auth_digest-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-base-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mpm-prefork-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-modules-2.4.18-2-rosa2014.1.i586
apache-mod_php-5.6.23-3-rosa2014.1.i586
```

В доках написано, что `mod_deflate` поставляется вместе с Apache и его достаточно активировать. Тут его не вижу.

Пробовал два способа редактировав `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

и

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя неделю нашлось решение.
Все действия проделаны на `Apache_2.4.23`

1. Из репозитория почему то по умолчанию не тянулся сам модуль `mod_deflate.so` вместе с конфигом `mod_deflate.conf`. Хотя вроде как Apache должен быть собран с этим модулем изначально. Но при поиске по репозиторию на совпадения имен обнаружился отдельным пакетом, который и был стянут.
2. В глобальном конфиге Apache httpd.conf, расположенном в /etc/httpd/conf, подключаем модуль `mode_deflate.so`

   > LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
3. В `php.ini` необходимо поменять значение строки `zlib.output_compression` с `off` на `on`, т.е. должно быть

   > zlib.output_compression = on

У меня этот файл был в `/etc`.
И все данные начинают сжиматься!